div растягивается на весь экран
введите сюда описание изображения
c.net/4a5bx1aL.jpg

Код (HTML/CSS) надо вставлять текстом, а не картинкой. Тут не хватает собственно вопроса.

Попробуй задать display: inline-block, она будет занимать ширину по контенту.
Также можете использовать стили:
min-width: 300px; /*минимальная ширина*/
min-height: 300px; /*минимальная высота*/
max-width: 300px; /*максимальная ширина*/
max-height: 300px; /*максимальная высота*/
width: 200px; 
height: 200px;

